Packing multiple writes into single TCP packet
I have a sequence of send() calls to write bytes to a TCP socket. Is it possible to force the socket to only send TCP packets when they are either full (exceeding the MTU) or I explicitly indicate that I'm done sequentially calling send()?
Specifically, I have some code like:
// these are user-provided, I don't control these:

void* buf1;
size_t len1;
void* buf2;
size_t len2;
void* buf3;
size_t len3;

// I control this call sequence:

if (send(sck, buf1, len1, 0) < 0 ||
    send(sck, buf2, len2, 0) < 0 ||
    send(sck, buf3, len3, 0) < 0) {
  ...
}

And I'd like to somehow minimize the number of underlying packets that are sent.
This could be done by creating an intermediate buffer then after all the send calls, I could then manually send that buffer but I'd like to avoid creating an intermediate buffer because some of the data may be quite large and it would require an extra copy of that data. In other words, I am looking to zero-copy send the data. Is this possible?
Note: I am aware that TCP is not a packet-based protocol. I've searched around and there are a number of answers that give that pedantic response that packets don't really exist and while it's perhaps semantically true, it's not particularly helpful because there are still IP packets underneath.

You can use writev() to reduce the number of send() calls, at the very least.

Ohh I think writev() is what I'm looking for!

"And I'd like to somehow minimize the number of underlying packets that are sent." - the TCP stack is already trying to optimize this for you. See NAGLE algorithm. What do you need more than that?

"I've searched around and there are a number of answers that give that pedantic response that packets don't really exist and while it's perhaps semantically true, it's not particularly helpful because there are still IP packets underneath." - if such answers are helpful depends on the context. It is often said as response to an attempt by OPs to treat TCP as a message protocol (instead of byte stream) and assuming that there is a 1:1 relationship between send on one side and recv at the other. And such "pedantic" responses then explain why this assumptions is wrong

You could use setsockopt() and set the TCP_CORK option. And then clear it when you want to send the data. But I'm not sure if this will be any better than just letting TCP manage it all for you.

Thanks! TCP_CORK also looks like a great option I did not know about. I found this article as well: https://baus.net/on-tcp_cork/. @SteffenUllrich actually it outlines the exact situation we are running into as for why Nagle's algorithm is insufficient, we turned it off, and are trying to hint to TCP where logical packet boundaries lie.

@kevmo314: "we turned it off, and are trying to hint to TCP where logical packet boundaries lie." - this looks like a terrible idea to me. And it might break in subtile ways with changing MTU (like when a VPN or some other encapsulation is used), with more packet loss (packets will not be retransmitted - data will and data from multiple packets might be combined into a new one for retransmission). Also, recv will just look into the receive buffer where the "logical packet boundaries" are already lost. Messages (i.e. "logical boundaries") should be handled at application level, not TCP.

Appreciate the feedback. Our project is not governed by how things "should" work. This is clearly explained in the blog post I linked to as well.

You can do writev() to write them all in one shot.  But in any case, you cannot control how or when the socket interface will pack the data and send it.  It depends on network congestion, internal buffer size, MTU and several other causes.
TCP uses a MTU which is normally adjusted along the connection life, based on the MTUs of all the interfaces in the path between the connection sides.  This is dynamically calculated, based on the ICMP fragmentation needed packets received.  So, allowing the user to interfere on that fine tuned algorithm is a dangerous bend.  IMHO, the sooner the socket has the data ready to send, the sooner the receiver gets it.

Thanks, this ended up being the ticket! writev() + TCP_NODELAY improved our application's performance by ~50x.
